# How angular router lazy loading dependent modules entryComponents works without issue but not the custom lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

For some valid reason I am trying to remove routing(in this case its lazy one) from my angular 6 app. I am using `NgModuleFactoryLoader` to load dynamic components and modules. Refer below article

https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093

So I have a lazy module `ModuleA` which depends on `mat-dialog` which loads a component named `FilterComponent` part of entryComponent provided by another module `FilterModule` (already added to imports array of moduleA and not anywhere else).

```js
//Ignore the syntax
CompA {
  openDialog() {
    matDialog.open(FilterComponent)
  }
}

ModuleA {
  imports: [MatDialog, FilterModule],
  declaration: [CompA]
}

FilterModule {
  declaration: [FilterComponent],
  entryComponent: [FilterComponent]
}

FilterComponent { ...
}
```

With lazy routing in place mat-dialog is able to open the `FilterComponent` without any issue. But when I tried to open the dialog by loading the module successfully using custom methods I got below error

> No component factory found for FilterComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

There is one open bug in github as well but I am curious how lazy routing is working without any issue.

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16431

Answer (score 0):

If a component is part of a module and you want to use that component in other module,

then put the component in exports rather than in entry component.

```
FilterModule {
  declaration: [FilterComponent],
  exports: [FilterComponent]
}
```

Now this component becomes available to other component as well, whenever you import this module in any other module.

Comment: I am not using other component inside html. Its been used by mat dialog.